# Functional Components vs ES6 Classes in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

All of the examples and tutorials of **NextJs** pages which presented in its docs and other references are with functional components.

So, What about classes? What happens to `getInitialProps` (or other features that mentioned in docs) when a functional component replaces with an ES6 class. Is that page still a NextJS page after replacing?

Answer (score 4):

You can use class components (as I usually do), just make sure that you add the static keyword to the `getInitialProps` method:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        image: PropTypes.string
    };

    static getInitialProps() {
        return {...};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                // render gallery
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```